# Why the weird timestamp-like inclusion when piping ls to mkdir?

Tags: linux, bash, mkdir, ls, xargs

My computer is running Scientific Linux release 6.5 (Carbon).
I want to create a new set of directories in

```
/newset/
```

with the same names as another set of existing subdirectories in

```
/oldset/
```

Here are the subdirectories in /oldset/

```
$ ls /oldset/
A/
B/
C/
```

I tried this

```
$ cd /newset/
$ ls /oldset/ | xargs mkdir
```

Which makes directories with these names

```
$ ls /newset/
?[0m?[38;5;27mA?[0m/
?[38;5;27mB?[0m/
?[38;5;27mC?[0m/
?[m/
```

Not what I'm expecting. I also tried doing a for loop through the ls output with mkdir and got the same result. Can someone explain why the weird result?

Comment: What's the output from `alias ls`?  And try piping the output from `\ls ...`.

Comment: Looks like maybe the color control codes from the `ls` command are getting used perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are running ls aliased to `ls -F --color`.  I'm not at a box right now, but I think that's the right setting.  I also don't know why you are using xargs?  I'd use command substitution, but as Andrew pointed out, back-slash ls to turn off/ignore the alias.

```
 mkdir $( \ls /oldset)
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. With the alias to `ls -F --color` off it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place; use an array:

```
names=( /oldset/* )
cd /newset
mkdir "${names[@]#/oldset/}"
```

or use a loop, although this requires multiple calls to `mkdir` instead of just one.

```
for d in /oldset/*/; do
    mkdir /newset/"${d#/oldset}"
done
```

Comment: with `mkdir "${names[@}#/oldset/}"` I get a bad substitution error

Comment: I was still holding the shift key down from the `@` when I tried to type the `]`.